# how to define sqlalchemy orm models for difficult logic

Tags: sql, orm, sqlalchemy

i am using sqlalchemy for my project. I have difficult logic for define models.

**i have four database table**

```
item_type
- item_type_id(tinyint)
- item_type_name (varchar) --item_types can be "post(1)", "product(2)" , "gallery(3)"

tag
- tag_id(int)
- tag_name(varchar)

item_tag
- item_type_id (tinyint) 
- item_id (int) -- item_id is can be post_id or product_id or gallery_id
- tag_id(int)

post
- post_id
- post_title
- post_content
```

My Models

```
class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tag'

    tag_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)  
    tag_name = Column(String(255))


class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'post'

    post_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) 
    post_title = Column(String(255))
    post_title = Column(Text)

    #tags relation will be here


class ItemTag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item_tag'

    item_type_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("tag.tag_id"), primary_key=True)
```

**getting post tags sql (post_id = 12)**

```
SELECT TAG.*
FROM item_tag IT
INNER JOIN tag TAG ON IT.tag_id=TAG.tag_id
WHERE IT.item_type_id=1 AND IT.item_id=12
```

I do not know how to define relation in Post model for tags. What is the correct way for post tags relation?

Comment: Even if you define this relationship (using `primaryjoin`, `secondaryjoin` and `secondary`) and are able to perform the query (`select`), you will not be able to handle additions of new `Tag`s to the items.

Comment: Please take a look at [Generic Associations](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/examples.html#module-examples.generic_associations) examples to give you an idea what you need to implement to handle the whole logic transparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `primaryjoin` argument to `orm.relationship()` to specify complex join conditions: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#relationship-primaryjoin

For your specific case, you would define something like the following:

```py
from sqlalchemy import orm

class Post(Base):
    ...
    tags = orm.relationship('Tag',
        primaryjoin='and_(ItemTag.tag_id==Tag.tag_id, ItemTag.item_id==Post.post_id, ItemTag.item_type_id==1)')
```

I haven't tested this so it may need some modifications but hopefully this is enough to get you on the right track.

Comment: thanks. i added that and worked >> tags = relationship('ItemTag', primaryjoin = "and_(Post.post_id==foreign(ItemTag.item_id), ItemTag.item_type_id==2)" )

Answer (score 1):

after @dgilland's answer i found two solution.

**Solution 1**

```
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "post"

    tags = relationship('ItemTag', primaryjoin = "and_(Post.post_id==foreign(ItemTag.item_id), ItemTag.item_type_id==2)" ) 

class ItemTag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item_tag'

    item_type_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("tag.tag_id"), primary_key=True)
    tag = relationship(Tag, lazy="joined")
```

**Solution 2 (I choose this solution)**

```
ItemTag = Table("item_tag", Base.metadata,
    Column("item_type_id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("item_id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("tag_id", Integer, ForeignKey("tag.tag_id"), primary_key=True)
)

class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "post"

    tags = relationship('Tag',
            secondary=ItemTag,
            primaryjoin=ItemTag.c.tag_id==Tag.tag_id,
            secondaryjoin = and_( post_id==foreign(ItemTag.c.item_id), ItemTag.c.item_type_id==2, ItemTag.c.tag_id==Tag.tag_id),  
            backref=backref('posts', lazy="dynamic")
        )
```

both worked.